# How to upload image to Google Cloud Storage with GAE/Cloud Endpoints API method

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

Does anyone have an example of a GAE/Cloud Endpoints API method (in Java) that can take in an image from an Android app and upload it to Google Cloud Storage?

I cannot seem to find any samples on how to do this but it is possible from what I understand.

EDIT:
The tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/using-cloud-storage) shows how to add a dependency to google app engine in eclipse and upload/download an image to Google Cloud Storage. Is it possible to do this with Cloud Endpoints somehow..? After all, they are both Google App Engine.

I want to offload as much of the upload/download code into my Cloud Endpoints API method(s), rather than coding everything inside of Android. This would allow me to reuse my Cloud Endpoints API on other clients.

More info I found: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1#sample

Looks like this is the gradle dependency for the cloud endpoints backend?:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev66-1.21.0'
}
```

EDIT:

You should use this dependency inside cloud endpoints:

```
compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.5'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can upload file to Google *Storage* [using Json Api](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload)

You may or may not want to store file metadata to *datastore* thru Endpoints.

You may or may not want to authenticate your users thru Endpoints before give them possibility to store files to Storage.

What I want to say is that Storage / Endpoints / Datastore are three different things and you don't required to use them all together.

Useful link: https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly upload (large) files to an Endpoints API method but instead need to receive them using the blobstore (or GCS) (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/ ). This requires the following:

- Setup on your server a blobstore upload handler (which is just a regular webapp2 handler).
- Expose an Endpoints method that calls `blobstore.create_upload_url()`, and then returns the upload URL to your App.
- Within the App, upload the picture to that upload URL; the file will then be accessible within your upload handler, where you can move it to GCS, Datastore or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : https://github.com/thorrism/GoogleCloudExample

Enable Google Cloud Storage : => https://console.developers.google.com/apis

Generate and download a key P12 : => https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam
Create a folder named "assets" and place there your key :
=> app/src/main/assets/"yourKey.P12"

For everyone can access your uploaded file reading do not forget to add the permissions on your Bucket